# Forecasting multi-variate time series which all have low cardinality integer values (0,1,2,3,4)

Tags: time-series

I have a dataset which records the availability of 300 different e-vehicle stations around the country at 5 minute intervals.

A station can have an availability ranging from 0 to 4 (vehicles).

I would like to predict the next availability of a specific station based on its previous state, and also the previous states of all other stations.

What is the best approach for this?

My data set has autocorrelation - e.g. a station's availability oscillates daily, it is highest in the wee hours and lowest during morning and evening commutes. The availability between stations themselves are also correlated - e.g. a vehicle may be driven from station 1 and parked station 2. Stations around a particular geographical area may also have correlated availabilities as vehicles move from fringe to city over the morning commute (I did not encode the station's location data here, although it is available if needed)

I have looked up models like VAR+LSTM but the low cardinality of the dataset makes it unique and it is difficult to find such specific modelling approaches.

My data looks like this:

| timestamp | stn_1 | stn_2 | stn_3 | ... stn300 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3/7/2023 10:00 | 4 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 3/7/2023 10:05 | 4 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3/7/2023 10:10 | 4 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3/7/2023 10:15 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3/7/2023 10:20 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 3/7/2023 10:25 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 3 |

I have 300 columns and 3000 rows (~2 weeks worth of records)

Here is what the full 3000 rows look like for a selected station:

[image]